# Using win32 APIs in Windows Forms Projects

Tags: winapi, clr, mode

I need to use Win32 Functions like
GetForegroundWindow(),
ShowWindow(),
SetForegroundWindow(),
SendMessage(), 
GetWindow().......in my Windows Form Project in Visual C++ 2005 (CLR mode).
the error i get when i use these functions is
error C3861: 'GetForegroundWindow': identifier not found

Comment: It's called **P/Invoke**. [This site](http://pinvoke.net/) has all the information you'll ever need. Using that term, you can also search this site and find tons of duplicate questions.

Comment: If you find that you need more detailed instructions than you can dig up with your own searching, please edit your question (find the link at the bottom, underneath the tags) to include more details about the particular unmanaged Win32 API functions that you wish to call from managed code. That would make it much easier for me (and others) to provide detailed, working sample code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version of this question said this is C++/CLI code.  You don't need pinvoke to use the winapi, C++/CLI was designed as an interop language.  Just `#include <windows.h>` and directly call the API functions you want to use.  Nobody can really help you if you don't document the errors you get.